# How to Split a Dictionary By Key Inplace

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary with three (variable) items:

```
d = {"data": [1, 2, 3, 4], "id": 4, "name": "bob"}
```

I want to split this into two dicts without copying any data. Basically I want to remove the `id` and `name` keys into its own dictionary but only by specifying "I want all keys that aren't the "data" key.

I would like to avoid copying the "data" key-value item as it can be 15+MB in size, so if anything, extracting the other items and leaving the "data" key-value item intact is desired.

My attempt:

```
# This will create a new dict for the non "data" key items. Great!
# But I want the "data" key-value pair to remain in its own dictionary without having to copy it into a new dict
non_data_dict = {key: d[key] for key in d.keys() - ['data']}
```

My desired result:

```
data_dict = {"data": [1,2,3,4]}
non_data_dict = {"id": 4, "name": "bob"}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "without copying any data?"

Comment: *'without having to copy it into a new dict"* - Why? What do you have against that?

Comment: @KellyBundy The "data" key's value can be 15+MB in size. so I'd like to not move that data around. The non "data" keys are not typically large so I want to be able to extract them freely without copying the original "data" key-value item

Comment: Huh? Are you talking about explicitly making a copy of the list? Why?

Comment: @KellyBundy Yeah youre right I don't understand it and thats why I am here to ask a clarifying question? Why do you have to be so rude?

Comment: Where was I rude?

Comment: @KellyBundy I am here to ask questions and learn. Not be told "I don't understand Python". It is people like you who give the programming community a gatekeeping mentality. Please be more helpful and offer solutions rather than attack one's ability to understand. I misunderstood that ```pop``` moves the item from the dict and into a new dict.

Comment: But it does seem you don't understand it, so I think pointing your misunderstanding out is helpful. It's something fundamental about Python, not just about `pop`.

Comment: @KellyBundy How is that helpful? You could offer a solution like " ```pop``` mutates the original dict and moves the item into the new one so copying does not matter". Its like telling a student who wants to multiply that they "dont understand addition because they made a mistake. Its an uncalled for attitude and deterring people from learning.

Comment: Like, if you instead do `newdict = {"data": d["data"]}` so that the value is both in the original dict and in the new dict, do you think that there was some expensive copying?

Comment: @KellyBundy So ```d["data"]``` is not copying? it is referencing the original data? Is that what you are saying? To me I interpret it as creating a new object that is copying data from the other ```d```. If that is not the case, then I learned something new today. That was my goal of asking this question.

Comment: Yes. That's fundamentally how Python works.

Comment: @KellyBundy Thank you for teaching me something new. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about [`pop`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=pop#dict.pop)*'ing* the `data` ?

```
data_dict = {"data": d.pop("data")}; non_data_dict = d
```

Output :

```
print(f"{data_dict=}", f"{non_data_dict=}", sep="\n")

data_dict={'data': [1, 2, 3, 4]}
non_data_dict={'id': 4, 'name': 'bob'}
```

Comment: This seems reasonable, but I'd like to avoid copying the ```data``` into a new dict as it can be quite large. If anything, I'd just want to pop the non-```data``` keys into a new dict.

Comment: It seems I could just do this:
```d = {"data": [1, 2, 3, 4], "id": 4, "name": "bob"}
non_data_dict: dict = {key: d.pop(key) for key in d.keys() - ['data']}
print(f"data_dict: {d}, non_data_dict: {non_data_dict}")```

Comment: Yes, that variant works too.

Comment: @Coldchain9 What does it matter how large `data` is?